# Insert sections of zeros into numpy array using zip and np.insert

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, zip

I cut out the zeros of a numpy array, do some stuff and want to insert them back in visual purposes. I do have the indices of the sections and tried to insert the zeros back in with numpy.insert and zip but the index runs out of bounds, even though I start at the lower end. Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5])
a = a[a != 0]  # cut zeros out
zero_start = [3, 9, 13]
zero_end = [5, 10, 15]

# Now insert the zeros back in using the former indices
for ev in zip(zero_start, zero_end):
    a = np.insert(a, ev[0], np.zeros(ev[1]-ev[0]))

>>> IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12
```

Seems like he is not refreshing the array size inside the loop. Any suggestions or other (more pythonic) approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: Keep a copy of `a==0`, and use that to copy the nee values to a zeros array.  `res=np.zeros...`; `res[mask]=new_values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1:** Using [`indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#) -

```
# Get all zero indices
idx = np.concatenate([range(i,j+1) for i,j in zip(zero_start,zero_end)])

# Setup output array of zeros
N = len(idx) + len(a)
out = np.zeros(N,dtype=a.dtype)

# Get mask of non-zero places and assign values from a into those
out[~np.in1d(np.arange(N),idx)] = a
```

We can also generate the actual indices where `a` had non-zeros originally and then assign. Thus, the last step of masking could be replaced with something like this -

```
out[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(N),idx)] = a
```

---

**Approach #2:** Using [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) given `zero_start` and `zero_end` as arrays -

```
insert_start = np.r_[zero_start[0], zero_start[1:] - zero_end[:-1]-1].cumsum()
out = np.insert(a, np.repeat(insert_start, zero_end - zero_start + 1), 0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [755]: a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5])
     ...: a = a[a != 0]  # cut zeros out
     ...: zero_start = np.array([3, 9, 13])
     ...: zero_end = np.array([5, 10, 15])
     ...: 

In [756]: s0 = np.r_[zero_start[0], zero_start[1:] - zero_end[:-1]-1].cumsum()

In [757]: np.insert(a, np.repeat(s0, zero_end - zero_start + 1), 0)
Out[757]: array([1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5])
```

Comment: Mhh, so I should use your code instead of zip? Can't get it run right now, resulting array is still of length 9.

Comment: @NumbThumb You sure about that? What's the `idx` you are getting?

Comment: Got it, looked for the wrong variable, "out" yields the result! Thanks alot, will now dig in and try to understand the idea behind it, I'm not used to masking.

Comment: Tested it on my actual problem and your "edit" actually achieved the right results where the original solution seemed to fail. Accepting answer now, two valid, short and great approaches!

Comment: @NumbThumb Check out the fresh one : `Approach #2` too! :)